# Doctrine2 Class Table Inheritance - what is correct syntax?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I use Class Table Inheritance, Doctrine 2 duplicates parent class properties in child class.

Example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\MyParentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_parent")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"my_child" = "MyChild"})
 */
class MyParent
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
   */
  protected $code;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\MyChildRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_child")
 */
class MyChild extends MyParent
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
   */
  protected $name;
}
```

---

When I call doctrine:generate:entities, class MyChild changes to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Rail\RussiaBundle\Entity\MyChildRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_child")
 */
class MyChild extends MyParent
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
   */
  protected $name;

  /**
   * @var integer
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $code;
}
```

(I omitted generated methods)

---

So, as you see, properties $id and $code are copied to class MyChild.

What I am doing wrong?
What is correct syntax for Class Table Inheritance?

I use Doctrine 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

If you change protected fields to private it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok and correct. You can remove dublicated stuff, of course if you do not want to modify it.